# store string values in fileoutputstream

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I would like to store my string values as a text file and hence i declared like

```
String item1, item2;
//code...
item1=arraylist.getItem1();
item2=arraylist.getItem2();
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
fos = openFileOutput(item1, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(item2.getBytes());
fos.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

//code....
```

But am getting an error of

```
1)java.lang.illegalargumentexception file contains a path separator
```

and my textfile in data/data/my package dir couldn't be opened and displays a message of

```
opendir failed permission denied android adb
```

What am doing wrong here and how can i store and see the values of my string in a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolved this issue. I created a new class and instantiated this class in the previous class and my codings are:

```
public void Class1(String item1, String item2, Context context)
        {
         FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = context.openFileOutput("newfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(item1.getBytes());
                fos.write(item2.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and i instantiated this class as

```
Class1 main = new Class1();
tracklog.Logger(item1, item2,this);
```

Hence illegal argument exception error got resolved. Hope this may help someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) java.lang.illegalargumentexception file contains a path separator

openFileOutput() doesn't accept paths, only a file name. If you want to create a file using a path try:

```
BufferedWriter writer;
try {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> 2) opendir failed permission denied android adb

In android you cannot access files in in your phone. If you need to access the file then you need to save it somewhere accessible such as SD card.

Comment: i moved fileoutput stream in a separate file and instantiate this in the previpus activity like SecondClass.save(name, data); but still am getting the same error